# How to install pyzmq python package in windows 10

Tags: python, package, pyzmq

When I tried to install pyzmq package in python, I always get this error message

```
PS C:\python37-32> pip install pyzmq
Failed building wheel for pyzmq
building 'zmq.libzmq' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visu
```

So I tried to fix it in two different ways:
Option 1: I downloaded Microsoft Visual C++ 14.00 --> It doesn't work
I downloaded the wheel "pyzmq-17.0.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl" and tried to install it with the pip install comannd --> It doesn't work

Does anyone can give me an advice how I can install the package? That would be great

Answer (score 1):

I try the following solution and it works for me. Solution:

1. Download an appropriate file from [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).
   For win10 as I use, just download: `pyzmq-18.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`
2. install this file from local with pip:

```
pip install download_directory/pyzmq-18.1.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your setup tools:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with this command:

```
pip install --upgrade pyzmq
```